# 'DirectoryInfo' is a type in 'IO' and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, io, directoryinfo

I continualy recieve this error no matter what i try please try help,
I'm trying to display the the directory information for a give drive

Example:

```
C:\ NTFS  500 000 000 Bytes
```

code:

```
Private Sub BtnCheckDestination_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCheckDestination.Click
    Dim hdrive As Int64
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("H:")

    di = IO.DirectoryInfo("H:\").ToString

    TxtDestination.Text = (di).ToString
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you create an instance of `DirectoryInfo`:

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("H:")
```

Note that `di` is of type `DirectoryInfo` now.

In the next line, you try to use the type `DirectoryInfo` as an expression by using parenthesis (which won't work, that's what the compiler tells you) and you try to call `ToString()` on that:

```
di = IO.DirectoryInfo("H:\").ToString
```

You proprably want to call `ToString()` on the instance you just created. Also, you'll try to change the type of `di` to `string`, which will work if you set `OPTION STRICT OFF`, but it is generally not a good practice.

---

So you can just use:

```
Dim di = New IO.DirectoryInfo("H:\")
TxtDestination.Text = di.ToString()
```

Nonetheless, it seems you're looking for the `DriveInfo` class instead, e.g.:

```
Dim di = new DriveInfo(@"H:\");
TxtDestination.Text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} Bytes", di.Name, di.DriveFormat, di.AvailableFreeSpace)
```

Comment: thank you, please excuse my terrible syntax i've been at this for the past two day almost non stop, your solution works but only outputs the drive path as such: H:\ i nee it to display as such H:\ NTFS 500 000 000 Bytes

Comment: Use the DriveInfo class instead. See my updated answer for an example.